# What should a son do if he knows that his mother has committed a crime?

Tags: sin

What should a son do if he knows that his mother has committed a crime?

For example, the mother is accused of stealing a baby and falsifying documents. She is sued and the son gives a large amount of money to help her, despite knowing she is guilty. He says he is acting according to Islam.

Comment: Is the son giving that money as a payment for penalty/fee or as a bribe?

Comment: As a bribe to the judge not to get punishment according to the law

Comment: Then it is not about mother-son relationship, but bribery.

Comment: What is the difference? The person says he gives bribe because it is his mother. I was not born a Muslim, That's why I don't understand this difference.

Comment: The difference is that, in my humble opinion, you are not asking the correct question. A more appropriate question would be **"Is it permissible for a son to bribe a judge in order not to get punishment for his mother according to the established law?"** In fact, the mother-son relationship does not effect the ruling on this case. Hence, I deem the question is not put correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the way how you put my question is part of what I wanted to know. The other part is about the attitude of children to the actions of their parents which are illegal or present a sin.

Comment: then you should probably edit the question and make it clearer for readers.

Comment: Could you please help me edit the question because I am afraid of putting it wrongly again as such questions are very subtle ones.Could you advise how to formulate the question.

Comment: @ozbek I think part of Fatimahon's question is whether or not the mother-son relationship has any effect on what the son should do, so it is a relevant detail.

Comment: @Fatimahon Try asking the question as ozbek phrased it, and include the relevant details that you haven't included in the post (i.e. that the son bribed a judge).

Answer (score 2):

One should deal justly with others even if it is a near relative.

The question does not specify how he is helping her, is it by assisting in the falsification of documents or giving a false testimony, if so then his claim of acting according to Islam is not a valid justification.

> And do not approach the orphan's property except in a way that is best
>   until he reaches maturity. And give full measure and weight in
>   justice. We do not charge any soul except [with that within] its
>   capacity. **And when you testify, be just, even if [it concerns] a
>   near relative. And the covenant of Allah fulfill. This has He
>   instructed you that you may remember** (6:152)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be within the boundaries of Islam. I'll give you two boundaries:

**Boundary 1**
*لا طاعه مخلوق فی معصیه خالق*

*No obedience to a creature in the disobedience of the creator!*

**Boundary 2**

*وَقَضَىٰ رَبُّكَ أَلَّا تَعْبُدُوا إِلَّا إِيَّاهُ وَبِالْوَالِدَيْنِ إِحْسَانًا ۚ إِمَّا يَبْلُغَنَّ عِندَكَ الْكِبَرَ أَحَدُهُمَا أَوْ كِلَاهُمَا فَلَا تَقُل لَّهُمَا أُفٍّ وَلَا تَنْهَرْهُمَا وَقُل لَّهُمَا قَوْلًا كَرِيمًا*

*‍And your Lord has decreed that you not worship except Him, and to parents, good treatment. Whether one or both of them reach old age [while] with you, say not to them [so much as], "uff," and do not repel them but speak to them a noble word.‍‍‍‍*

Conclusion:

You should not allow her to steal a baby and falsify documents (boundary 1) while you treat, speak with her with total respect (boundary 2)

Answer (score -1):

Allah in the Quarn says

**"And if they contend with you that you should associate with Me what you have no knowledge of, do not obey them, and keep company with them in this world kindly, and follow the way of him who turns to Me, then to Me is your return, then will I inform you of what you did-- (Quran 31:15)"**

If the son did what he did intentionally and knowing that the thing he helped her for is Haram, he should ask forgivenes because he committed a sin.

Since when does Islam say help your mother in doing unlawful thing, that's not Islam. As the verse says clearly, do not obey them in unlawful actions. And this include, buying alcohol for them, buying pork. etc...

Comment: The OP does not mention or imply that the son is helping his mother in wrongdoing.

Comment: I do not understand who is OP.

Comment: @Fatimahon OP means original poster. He is referring to you, cause you are the original poster of this question.